# Is there a way to capture panorama using html5 and javascript on a web app by device camera?

Tags: html, camera, panoramas

I want to capture panorama image using html5 and javascript.
I tried using 
`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`
But this does not provide panorama feature.
I searched a lot but didn't find any solution so is it even possible or not?